# Backbone & REST API : Session Handling

Tags: api, rest, session, backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-4

I am in the midst of planning a saas app and have been stuck trying to figure out how I want to handle my session management. Here's the scenario:

Server 1: REST API, Rails 4 w/ rails-api gem

Server 2: Front-end, Rails 4, BackboneJS/MarionetteJS

- These servers, eventually, will be part of a cluster of similar servers.
- The applications are separate because there will also be a mobile app using the REST API and we plan on having 3rd party applications tie into our database via the API.

I've boiled it down to 2 scenarios:

1) Use access_tokens only for authentication on the front-end:

- User logs in and sends over email and password over https
- They are authenticated via the api and it returns an access_token
- All future requests made on the front-end use this access token

2) User database sessions on the front-end and then access_tokens for api calls

- User logs in and is authenticated via devise on the frontend server (storing session info in the DB)
- An access_token is generated for them and added to the Backbone app initialization for future api requests

I favor #2 simply because every time the user changes the page, I can easily see if they are still authenticated and if not, boot them back to the login page.

But #1 keeps things easy in the sense that the frontend server deals with just that: the frontend stuff.

Does any suggest one method over another? Why?

Does anyone have any other alternatives?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

You're reinventing the wheel by doing using an `access_token`. Devise already generates a cookie and sends it back when signing in. Just parse this cookie out when the client logs in:

- User logs in with backbone app (post request is sent to API server)
- Devise does it's thing and authenticates the user, generates the session_id and sends it back in an HTTP Set-cookie header.
- backbone app parses the cookie out and caches the session_id value (think of this as your access_token)
- each subsequent api call sends the cookie value in an HTTP Cookies header as session_id=cookie-value-here

Note your session cookie name is custom to your app and can be configured in an initializer via:

```
# /config/initializers/session_store.rb
YourRailsApp:Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_your_rails_app_session'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @diego.greyrobot. The one major downside I see to this is that I would have to handle 2 types of authentication. The reason for that is that users will also be using this as a traditional REST API and requesting an oauth access token and using that for their api calls

Comment: Then why not make oauth the only authentication method? Wouldn't the access_token method also be a 2nd form of authentication? The point was to not reinvent the session token since it's already provided by devise via the session cookie.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I think that storing the session (for usage tracking and vanity stats) is all fine and dandy but I'll just keep it to a straight oauth process.

Send in email/pass, start session, generate token, send back token, authenticate every request via token. On logout, expire session, expire token.